# Extracting Numbers in Word Format From a String

Tags: java

So what I am trying to do is extract numbers that are in word format in a long String, i.e. a song, and return each of their numerical values, in order to add them all up. So I'd like to calculate the sum of all of the numbers in the text. This has to work for any piece of text and for all numbers up to a trillion.

So I broke the string down into tokens and stored them in a String []. And I divided up the possible numbers in word format into:

- LARGEST: thousand, million, billion, trillion
- HUNDRED: hundred
- TENS: twenty, thirty, forty, fifty, sixty, seventy, eighty, ninety
- UNITS: one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine
- SPECIALS: ten, eleven, twelve, thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, sixteen, seventeen, eighteen, nineteen

I believe that these are the only words that it will need to recognize. I began reading the tokenized string from right to left and then when I came across a unit, special or tens as the first number I hit, I would then set it's numerical value and check if the word before was also a number and whether to add or multiply etc. i.e. First number hit is a two, if the number before is sixty, then I would just add it to sixty and check the word before that and so on. However, when implementing it, it seems like an extremely long way around it. Does anyone have any ideas of how I could implement this in a swifter manner? Thanks for any replies, it is greatly appreciated and if I am not making it clear what I need to do then please say so. An example of it working would be: "Nine Million rockets turned Three times and met Twenty Two Aliens", it would extract, `Twenty Two` as `2`, then `20 = 22`, then extract Three as 3, and then Nine Million as `1,000,000 x 9 = 9,000,000`

```
9,000,000 + 22 + 3 = 9,000,025
```

Comment: You'll get a better result if you post what code you have.

Comment: the problem is why your code should consider Twenty Two as 22 and not 40 (20 x 2) or Nine Million as 1,000,009 (1,000,000 + 9). So in short when you'll know where to distinguish between addition and multiplication?

Comment: The way I was going to go about that was, if a unit, tens or hundred is the word before one of the largest, or a unit is the word before a hundred, then it will mean multiplying the two. If this is not the case then it will be addition.

Comment: i.e. Two Hundred Thousand, would mean 1,000 x 100 = 100,000. 100,000 x 2 = 200,000, where as one hundred and sixty two, would mean, 2 + 60 = 62, +100 = 162

Comment: The issue I have is more that, the way that my logic approaches this question is quite difficult to implement. i.e. every possibility that the largest, hundreds, tens, units, specials could be aligned within the text.